# How could I monitor a c++ queue, a globle variable, in VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstring>
    #include<queue>
    #include<set>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    queue<node*> Q;
```

When I try to add this variable to my VScode monitor, the only thing I could see is a bunch of addresses and I have no idea how to monitor the element I add. Could someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: That's because a `node*` *is* an address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Here, no one can help with your question without knowing what `node` is?